# windows task scheduler failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, php-7, taskscheduler

This works fine when I run it for testing with PHPUnit on development.

But when running this script from windows task scheduler in production

```
<?php

require("./task_config.php"); 
// do stuff...
```

I keep getting this error in the log:

`PHP Warning:  require(./task_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\path\to\working\scripts\debug.php on line 5`

Out of desperation, I removed the current directory notation and tried

```
<?php

require("task_config.php"); 
// do stuff...
```

And it works. The settings I'm using in the actions tab are:

> Action: `Start a program`
>
> Program/script: `php.exe`
>
> Add arguments:  `-f C:\path\to\working\scripts\debug.php`
>
> Start in: `C:\path\to\working\scripts\`

Does windows not understand dot slash?  I've used it in web page scripting, so I'm confused as to why windows seems to be barfing on it when using PHP in the command line.  Am I doing something wrong in the scheduler or does windows just not understand?

Clarification: dot slash works on the command line in development with phpunit (development is a separate system running php 5.6 accessed via mapping; phpunit runs on my local machine with php 7). Production is running php 7.

Comment: 1) Under what account is the script running 2) does that account have access rights (probably read and execute, may be more) to that directory and file? 3) who wouldn't barf on PHP?

Comment: I think it's `require`. I've seen it not like relative paths before.

Comment: @Will 1) SYSTEM, 2) yes - it works without the dot slash, 3) well... you work with what you're given :/

Comment: @admcfajn perhaps it is a php quirk; odd that it works in CL with one application and not another. If so, I guess I'll just have to live with it :/

Comment: @TimMorton if it's working in one, but not another that's interesting. Do the separate apps have their own php.ini files / environment settings? Have you tried switching out `require` for `include`, `include_once`, or `require_once`?

Comment: @admcfajn yes, they do have different php.ini files.  That's a good idea to chase down.  And swapping out might point out the glitch too.  This is at work, so I'll have to come back to it.  Thanks for readjusting my focus.

Comment: @TimMorton happy to help :) second set of eyes, right?

Answer (score 1):

Task scheduler loads the `C:\Windows` by default as a directory
you can fix this issue by adding

```bat
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
```

to your bat or cmd file header

Comment: Well, I've slept a few times since asking this question... Good answer, addresses the problem and proposes a solution!  I'll have to dig up the project that generated the question and try it out.  Might take a while, but it this fixes it I'll be sure to accept it.  Thanks for jumping in!